# Error while starting the integration node in IIB 10.0.0.24

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

Getting the following error while creating and starting the integration node in IIB 10.0.0.24 on windows 10 Pro 64-bit

**Begin running task [The local integration node is being created]
mqsicreatebroker DEV_NODE -i LocalSystem -S yes
BIP8071I: Successful command completion.
End running task [The local integration node is being created]**

**Begin running task [The local integration node is being started]
mqsistart DEV_NODE
BIP8015E: The component cannot be started.
The command cannot start the required component.
The possible causes of this error are: insufficient user ID permissions; lack of system resources (not enough memory); the WebSphere MQ environment is not configured correctly for the user who is running the command (for example, the mqm library is missing from the user's path).
The task was unsuccessful: The command failed.**

I have added the username in the mqbrkrs, though my user in not a local user but in one of the network domains.

Kindly, help.

Comment: If you think this is an MQ error, please also look in the MQ error log to see whether anything is reported there.

Comment: You can see details of errors in the event log.

Comment: Your question is too broad. The error provides many possible root causes. You should explain which steps you took for each possible root cause, and what was the result - e.g., you used elevated privileges, system memory is ok.

Comment: In the event log it says DEV_NODE service failed to start due to following error:
the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Comment: Also, my system specs are i7-7700 CPU 16 GB of RAM 1 TB HDD and Windows 10 pro 64bit OS Version 20H2. There is no MQ installed on the system.